# Binomial distribution - Probability of being bigger than the expected value

Tags: inequality, expected-value, binomial-distribution

Suppose we have a random variable `X` with binomial distribution `B(n, p)`. I'm interested in the probability `P(X ≥ E[X])`. In particular, is there some inequality for how this probability changes as `n` and `p` grow? Is there some lower and upper bound for this probability? I was not able to find any resource on this topic.

For context, I am using some probabilistic computational model and I'm trying to see how it behaves as `n` (the size of the input) grows.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, the answer is a bit boring. The binomial distribution is symmetric about its mean, so the probability that it exceeds its mean is just $(1/2)(1-Pr(X = E[X])$. For generic $p$, the expectation will be non-integer so the answer is just $1/2$. Otherwise, the probability of equaling the mean goes down  as the variance of the distribution increases, so the probability goes from slightly below $1/2$ to approaching $1/2$.

Comment: It's a symmetric distribution, so if $X$ is not exactly at the mean it has an equal chance of being above or below the mean.

Comment: Wait, if $p$ is not $1/2$, then the distribution not symmetric about the mean, so it's not quite that simple. For example, if $p$ = 0.99 and $n=100$ then it has greater chance of being above the mean of $99$ than below, since the see-saw balance of the histogram is at $99$ but the left tail extends much further than the right tail, so the right tail must have more data in it, so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are looking for is Large Deviation and the rate function.

Let $X_{i}$ be identical and independent (IID) random variables and X ~ $X_{1}$ with summation and moment generating function

$$
S_n={\sum_{i=1}^n}X_i
$$

$$
M(\theta) = E[e^{\theta X}] < \infty, 
$$

$$
\theta ∈(-\gamma,\gamma), \gamma>0
$$
and if $a ≥E[X]$ and $\theta^*$>0 such that

$$
\lambda^*(a) = sup[{\theta}a-\lambda_{X}(\theta)|\theta>0]=\theta^*a-\lambda_{X}(\theta^*)
$$
where $\lambda_X(\theta)=ln(M_X(\theta))$ is the logmoment.

Then, the probability $P(S_n>na)$ is bounded by upper and lower bounds tightly for every $n>n_{\delta}$ and $\delta$ by:
$$
exp(-n(\lambda^*(a)+\delta))<P(S_n>na)<exp(-n(\lambda^*(a)-\delta))
$$

For your problem, we have ${X_i}$'s as Bernoulli(p) that are iid. Also, your binomial is: $S_n={\sum_{i=1}^n}X_i$. All conditions are satisfied and Large Deviation Limits can be applied now.

Finding the moment generating function of ${X_i}$.

$$
E[e^{{\theta}X}]=pe^{\theta}+(1-p)
$$

$$
\lambda_X(\theta)=ln(M_X(\theta))=ln(pe^{\theta}+(1-p))
$$

$E[S_n]=np$ and we are asked to find bound for $P(Sn>np)$, which we now know the bounds for.

The rest is just plugging in $a=x$ in the explanation above and maximizing the rate function $\lambda^*(x)$ with respect to the $\theta$.

Hope this helps, sorry if I miswrote something, I am new here.

Answer (score 0):

Since $E(X)=np$ for binomial, $P(X\gt np)=\sum\limits_{k=m}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$, where $m=\lfloor np\rfloor +1$.

Comment: $E(X)=np$ doesn't it?